# HAL+JSON hypermedia type not a media type for REST?

Tags: api, restful-architecture, media-type

Can the HAL+JSON hypermedia type be used in a way that creates a RESTful service?

From what I have read, the client of a RESTful API should not need to treat different resources with special cases. The media type should instead be used to describe what resources are expected to look like.

The [HAL spec](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) gives this example:

```
GET /orders

{
  ...
  "shippedToday": 20,
  ...
}
```

```

As a client of this sample HAL+JSON-serving API, I seem to need to know that an "order" has an attribute of `shippedToday`. That seems to go against the constraint that the client should not need to understand the representation's syntax.

This is not a critique of HAL. The question is to help my (and others') understanding of RESTful API design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the HAL+JSON hypermedia type be used in a way that creates a RESTful service?

Yes, definitely.

The API should have a billboard URL, which in your case could be `/`.

This is the entry point from which humans and ideally even machines can start to discover your API.

According to the [HAL specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08) a resources representation contains an optional property called `"_links"` which is described here:

> It is an object whose property names are link relation types (as
> defined by [RFC5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988)) and values are either a Link Object or an array
> of Link Objects.

So these links represent the hypermedia part of your API. The relations can be [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xml)-registered relations or you can use your own extension relations.

Relations should not be ambiguous. Their names should be unique. That's why it is recommended to use URIs from your own domain as names for your own relations. These URIs identify a resource that represents the relation and contains an API documentation, a human or machine readable documentation of your relation.

In your case this would be a relation that describes the state transition to the `/orders` resource. This should also include a description and explanation of the response and therefore document that e.g. the `/orders` resource represents a list of orders and has a property called "shippedToday" with a value of type number.

Here is an example response for a `GET / HTTP/1.1` request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json

{
    "_links": {
        "self": { "href": "/" },
        "http://yourdomain.com/docs/rels/orders": { "href": "/orders" },
    }
}
```

Under `http://yourdomain.com/docs/rels/orders` there should be the API docs.

Comment: I've read this a couple of times now and it doesn't really further my understanding of what HAL _links provides. Are you saying that I should understand from the _links properties that I should read documentation provided at "/docs/rels/orders" to learn how the "/orders" URL is a HAL set of end-points offering CRUD functionality on Orders? I just seems counter-intuitive to me that I should use the label of a property as a URL.

Comment: @Adam Yes, it is indeed a little counter-intuitive. And your understanding of it is correct as far as I can tell. To make link relation types more readable, you can use CURIEs (see http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html).